# Covid certificate for entry from Switzerland to Italy

Tags: schengen, covid-19, italy, switzerland

[Italy](https://www.salute.gov.it/portale/nuovocoronavirus/dettaglioContenutiNuovoCoronavirus.jsp?lingua=english&id=5412&area=nuovoCoronavirus&menu=vuoto&tab=3) requires an EU COVID-19 Green Certificate for entry from Schengen countries.

However, the Swiss digital certificate is not yet integrated into the EU system.

The [EU website](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/eu-digital-covid-certificate_en) says

> Phase-in period: if a Member State is not yet ready to issue the new certificate to its citizens, other formats can still be used and should be accepted in other Member States.

Does Switzerland fall under this and what formats are acceptable to Italy? Is the Swiss digital certificate nonetheless acceptable? Or are more traditional formats (e.g. vaccination booklet, separate attestations) required?

Comment: By what mode of travel?  I can't speak to entering Italy, but I entered Switzerland by air from Iceland 16 days ago, and traveled by municipal bus to France and back 8 days ago, and nobody looked at anything.

Comment: @phoog All that was before the entry into application of the EU Digital COVID Certificate Regulation on July 1st. Not that it necessarily changes anything, but if someone asks, you'd better have the right paperwork.

Comment: @jcaron I am in any event not eligible for a Swiss certificate because the Canton of Geneva issues certificates to those who were vaccinated abroad only if they received one of two vaccines, and I received a different vaccine.  But given my experience 8 days ago (when I brought my US certificate, but nobody asked to see it), I seriously doubt they've started checking the vaccination status of passengers on the bus between Geneva and Ferney-Voltaire.  I'll probably be going back (or trying to) sometime this week.  I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @phoog Mainly for air and train travel where I heard some checks may happen. Yeah I don't think anyone checks on local buses, they don't check on Lausanne-Evian ferries either.

Comment: @xngtng I flew from the US to Switzerland via Iceland two weeks ago and nobody checked my vaccination certificate (which exempted me from testing requirements in both Iceland and Switzerland). It was truly weird. Iceland required me to certify online that I had a negative COVID test; the web site did not allow for the exception applicable to vaccinated people; and Icelandair of course wouldn't let me board without registering online, so I lied about the test. Neither the airline, nor Icelandic authorities, nor Swiss authorities asked for any documentation, neither of tests nor of vaccinations.

Comment: According to the new today, it seems that Italy is systematically checking passengers at least for EC trains...

Comment: @phoog it’s all security theater. Similar experience with Czech Republic - no one asked for the test or the local website registration printout except the airline.

Comment: @JonathanReez but having airlines enforce this sort of thing on pain of fines on the order of a few thousand dollars/euros/pounds is a long established practice.  In my case even _the airline_ didn't ask to see any documents -- other than my (faulty) registration.

Comment: By now the linked website says the Switzerland is fully integrated.

Answer (score 5):

You should carry the paper documentation of the vaccinations. Now in EU there is a transition period, where also the "old" paper certifications are valid, with the hope that soon also the electronic certificate will be recognized by EU. OTOH there is a lot of geopolitics involved, so...we never know.

Note: very recently Italy changed rules for border crossing, and now they check much more compared to last week, e.g. all passengers on long distance trains.

EDIT/UPDATE:

Some additional passes were done, to approve Swiss electronic certificate as "green pass". It seems that now it lacks just the last step: the political green light (so just to make it official), and such green light it is expected within few days.

UPDATE #2:

Now the Swiss vaccination certificate is valid in the EU.

Comment: Thanks, apparently Italy has also recognized the Swiss digital ones before EU announcement according to RSI but they said it could depend on the border guard. The Swiss certificate will be homologated from July 9 (so need to wait one day more).

Answer (score 0):

The [International Certificate of Vaccination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Vaccination_or_Prophylaxis#Required_components) (ICVP), introduced in in the early 1930's, is and will remain the main form of, internationally recognized, proof (**certification**) of which vaccinations a person has recieved

- and nothing more

Therefore, in situations where proof of vaccination is required, such as for entry from Switzerland to Italy, a *International Certificate of Vaccination* is sufficient.

This assumes that the person checking the certificate knows what to look for and what is considered to be valid.

In the present situation, where waiters are required to check these certificates, this poses a problem.

For this reason a QR-Code based digital solution has been developed.

But this solution **does not** replace the *International Certificate of Vaccination*, it only simplifies the process.

In the end, it is up to the traveler to insure has a needed documentation and that it is valid.

---

> [ICVP - Required components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Vaccination_or_Prophylaxis#Required_components)
> The main portion of the ICVP is a form for physicians to fill out when administering a vaccine. This section is mandated by the WHO's 2005 International Health Regulations, in which they provide a model of the document. It includes places for the traveller's name, date of birth, sex, nationality, national identification document, and signature. Below that is a row **for each vaccine administered**, in which the physician must include the **prophylaxis or vaccine administered, date, signature, manufacturer and batch number, dates valid, and an official stamp** from the administering centre.
>
> Below this, the document outlines requirements for validity. The ICVP is only valid for vaccines approved by the WHO. The form must be fully completed in English or French by a medical practitioner or authorized health worker and **must include the official stamp of the administering centre**. The certificate is valid for as long as the vaccines included are valid.

> This ICVP may possibly be considered to be invalid:
> [image]
>
> > - due to the missing official stamp of the administering centre

---

**Sources**:

- [International Certificate of Vaccination or Prophylaxis - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Vaccination_or_Prophylaxis#Required_components)